# Compute the integral $ \int \frac{\sin x + \cos x}{\sqrt{9 + 16 \sin{2x}}} \mathrm{dx}$

Tags: integration

How to compute this indefinite integral.

$$ \int \frac{\sin x + \cos x}{\sqrt{9 + 16 \sin{2x}}} \mathrm{dx}$$

Comment: make the substitution u=sinx-cosx and square this, does it help?

Comment: Mathematica says that the result is: $\frac{1}{4} \cos (x) \sqrt{\sec ^2(x)} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{16 \sin (2 x)+9} \sqrt{\sec ^2(x)}}{4-4 \tan (x)}\right)$

Comment: @Oldboy I wonder why the $\cos x\cdot\sqrt{\sec^2x}$.

Comment: @Zacky Thanks. The substitution indeed does solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Let $u=\sin x-\cos x$ so $du=(\cos x + \sin x)dx$ and $u^2=1-\sin 2x$. Your integral is then $$\int\frac{du}{\sqrt{25-16u^2}}=\frac{1}{4}\mathrm{arcsin}\frac{4u}{5}+C=\frac{1}{4}\mathrm{arcsin}\frac{4(\sin x-\cos x)}{5}+C.$$